# How to find ARA-M sample APDUs?

Tags: access-control

I am trying to interface an applet in my USIM and an  Android application.

I know that I have to install ARA-M applet on USIM in order to check access controls and submit my application-AID as a rule to communicate.

I checked [this](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/aram-applet) link and installed it on my sim, but I cannot communicate with this applet, all samples are using [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro). when I run a commands like `gp.exe --list`, it returns `0x57` from `ScardTransmit` function which means `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` and I don't know how to fix it.

Now I have 2 questions:

1) How can I fix GlobalPlatformPro error in order to run [ARA-M](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/aram-applet) samples?

2) How can I find standard commands for this applet (some sample APDUs to communicate and add access control rules)?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

There is a paper on the matter [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290527350_Open_Mobile_API_Accessing_the_UICC_on_Android_Devices). It is a good place to get started. Global Platform has a repository [here](https://github.com/GlobalPlatform/OMAPI-applets) where you can find ARA applet and four test applets to get started.

The [Global Platform Secure Element Access Control](https://globalplatform.org/specs-library/secure-element-access-control-v1-1/) can also be a useful reference for those who are at the start point, like me.